# Where can I find ConnectivityMonitor()?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-me, jxta

I want to thank you all for having patience for my strange questions.

I wonder where can I find the method ConnectivityMonitor() in JXTA 2.6? I am attaching a picture so you can get an idea.

.
.
.
.
.
 [image]

=============================picture 2====================

[image]

Comment: If you scroll to the top of the `.java` file, you'll see some import statements. Can you read the line containing `ConnectivityMonitor` for us please?

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I get the fellowing output. I have attached a new picture.

newpackage.​ConnectivityMonitor
public ConnectivityMonitor(PeerGroup inGroup)
Creates new form ConnectivityMonitor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If their is one of the tutorial of JXTA then you should have gotten the class in the same package as EDGE_A class.

See: [One tutorial](http://ppcast.googlecode.com/svn-history/r23/branches/jxse-tutorials-2.6/src/main/java/tutorial/connectivitymonitoring/) as example or download the tutorial from [JXSE Tutorial](http://jxse.kenai.com/Tutorials/Tutorials.html) and check out the connectivity example.